# How to prepare data for weka in word sense disambiguation

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka

I want to use weka for word sense diasambiguation. I prepared some files containing a Persian sentence, a tab, a Persian word, a tab and then an English word. they are in notepad++ in txt format. Now how should I use these files for weka? How should I change them?

The sample file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7wtvrvkiir80la/F.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The files should have the same number of columns. So I put the sentences in quotations, then a comma and the the English word in quotation. Above these, we should write proper relations and attributes.